# Android to React Native: TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, java, android, https, react-native

I am trying to convert an Android app into React Native, and I came across one of the following API requests on the Android app:

```
public Result checkModule(Bundle params) {
  String strURL = 

  HttpURLConnection conn = null;

  try {
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod(HttpVerb.GET.name());
    setBasicAuth(conn);
    conn.connect();
    Log.d("Req", "[" + conn.getRequestMethod() + "] to " + url.toString());

    String body = readStream(conn.getInputStream());
    return new Result(conn.getResponseCode(), body);
  }
}
```

And I tried my attempt to convert it like so to React Native:

```
export const practiceFetch = () => {
  var requestHeader = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }

  var request = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: requestHeader,
  }

  return dispatch => {
    fetch('https://apipractice.io:3000/monitor/module', request)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(payload => {
      console.log(‘Return success’)
      console.log(payload)

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error `TypeError: Network request failed`. And I tried adding `<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>`, yet getting the same error.

What may be the issue for the error? And how can I convert from Android to React Native properly?

Comment: You seem not to be passing the `request` configuration object to `fetch`. You'll need to pass that as the second argument, after the URL.

Comment: @jevakallio Sorry already did but left it out, but still getting the same error. Just made the edit.

Comment: Is this happening on only iOS, only Android, or both? Is the domain:port open to the internet?

Comment: @jevakallio Only iOS React Native. Sorry but what do you mean if domain:port is open to the internet? The API endpoint is being used by the native Android device and currently working.

Comment: I was just wondering if the web address you are calling actually exists and is working. In your code snippet the address https://apipractice.io:3000 does not exist, so that might cause the error.

Comment: @jevakallio How can I see if it exists? I believe the native android app works with the APIs

Comment: @jevakallio Also have I made the correct conversion from Android to React Native?